# Configure the selected control's Text of the user Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabs

I am creating a group of panels with labels in it. Depending on the requirement of the User. Kind of mimicking the Tab control here. Where like the Tab control's Title is editable, i would let the user to configure the name of the labels at design time. How possibly can i achieve it?

Comment: title will be given before the load or after the load??

Comment: after the user drags the user control onto the form. They can create n  number of panels with default name. I wish to let them select individual panels and edit the text.

Answer (score 0):

In the event Handler of the Label, change the label to a TextBox. When the TextBox looses focus, replace it with a Label again

Comment: i want things to happen at the design time...wherein events will be triggered at runtime

Comment: I cant understand you. How can earn the "user" the desing time data?

Comment: i just want to let the user have the flexibility to change the name of the label at design time

Comment: you mean while using your control in visual studio??

Answer (score 0):

Please chehk the following [thread](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/138024/Header-Editable-Tab-Control-in-WPF) (Header Editable Tab Control in WPF).

If you use WPF, then this is exactly what you need for your work. If you use another template, maybe still can add some tips. :)

Good luck